# ClassCastingException when redeploy war in wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, wildfly, classcastexception

I always get an error on redeploy a new version of my web app.

I have to undeploy and restart the server to get it working.

If i don't restart the server i get this message on deployment process:

> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext

Im running a Springboot Application as backend and Angular for frontend.

Here my maven dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because there are already (implicit) log4j API dependencies on WildFly. You can configure WildFly to not add it's own API logging dependency.

A) From **WildFly console:** Configuration -> Subsystems -> Logging configuration

change "Add Logging Api Dependencies" to **false**

B) By editing the **standalone.xml**:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
   <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
```

C) Alternatively, if you have a **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="logging"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
```

P.S This fixed it for me with same technology stack as you

[jboss doc about logging-api-dependencies](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Logging%20Configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should exclude **org.apache.logging.log4j**:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

as log4j:log4j was the old name

Comment: I have already excluded this package in spring-boot-starter-web in dependency

Comment: Then can you list the jar in your resulting application WEB-INF/lib ?